# react-bootstrap modal does not change its state

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

Need help! I am coding react app.
I have installed latest versions: react 16.2.0, react-dom 16.2.0, react-bootstrap 0.31.5, react-overlays 0.7.4

I am expecting that component has state.show = {false} and should not be appearing on the page load. But it appears. Also the button 'close' is not passing the boolean value to the state of the component.

this is my Modal Component: AddNewStoreModalDialog.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class AddNewStoreModalDialog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
  }

  open() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }

  close() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div id="add-new-store-modal">
        <Modal.Dialog show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>

          <Modal.Body>
            One fine body...
          </Modal.Body>

          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
            <Button bsStyle="primary">Save changes</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>

        </Modal.Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddNewStoreModalDialog;
```

this is where it is being inserted:
App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import StoreContainer from './components/StoreContainer'
import GoogleMap from './components/GoogleMap'
import NavBarHeader from './components/NavBarHeader'
import AddNewStoreModalDialog from './components/AddNewStoreModalDialog'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="App">
      <AddNewStoreModalDialog />
        <div class="header">
          <NavBarHeader />
        </div>
        <div class="main-container">
          <div class="left-container">
            <GoogleMap />
          </div>
          <div class="right-container">
            <StoreContainer />
          </div>
        </div>   
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

this is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

and index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/<version>/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyADa-s_wErrhpWEs1iLQDKVE2BOg-E92EU"></script>

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Console log:

```
index.js:2177 Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `show`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: show="false" or show={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with show={condition && value}, pass show={condition ? value : undefined} instead.
    in div (created by ModalDialog)
    in ModalDialog (at AddNewStoreModalDialog.js:25)
    in div (at AddNewStoreModalDialog.js:24)
    in AddNewStoreModalDialog (at App.js:12)
    in div (at App.js:11)
    in App (at index.js:7)
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ index.js:2177
printWarning @ warning.js:33
warning @ warning.js:57
validateProperty$1 @ react-dom.development.js:13555
warnUnknownProperties @ react-dom.development.js:13580
validateProperties$2 @ react-dom.development.js:13600
validatePropertiesInDevelopment @ react-dom.development.js:13639
setInitialProperties$1 @ react-dom.development.js:13906
finalizeInitialChildren @ react-dom.development.js:14989
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:8648
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:10132
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:10234
workLoop @ react-dom.development.js:10288
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:542
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:581
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:438
renderRoot @ react-dom.development.js:10366
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:11014
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:10967
requestWork @ react-dom.development.js:10878
scheduleWorkImpl @ react-dom.development.js:10732
scheduleWork @ react-dom.development.js:10689
scheduleTopLevelUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:11193
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:11231
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:15226
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:11102
renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:15225
render @ react-dom.development.js:15290
./src/index.js @ index.js:7
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:678
fn @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:88
0 @ registerServiceWorker.js:108
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:678
./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js.module.exports @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:724
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:724
index.js:2177 Warning: Unknown event handler property `onHide`. It will be ignored.
    in div (created by ModalDialog)
    in ModalDialog (at AddNewStoreModalDialog.js:25)
    in div (at AddNewStoreModalDialog.js:24)
    in AddNewStoreModalDialog (at App.js:12)
    in div (at App.js:11)
    in App (at index.js:7)
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ index.js:2177
printWarning @ warning.js:33
warning @ warning.js:57
validateProperty$1 @ react-dom.development.js:13489
warnUnknownProperties @ react-dom.development.js:13580
validateProperties$2 @ react-dom.development.js:13600
validatePropertiesInDevelopment @ react-dom.development.js:13639
setInitialProperties$1 @ react-dom.development.js:13906
finalizeInitialChildren @ react-dom.development.js:14989
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:8648
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:10132
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:10234
workLoop @ react-dom.development.js:10288
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:542
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:581
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:438
renderRoot @ react-dom.development.js:10366
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:11014
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:10967
requestWork @ react-dom.development.js:10878
scheduleWorkImpl @ react-dom.development.js:10732
scheduleWork @ react-dom.development.js:10689
scheduleTopLevelUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:11193
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:11231
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:15226
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:11102
renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:15225
render @ react-dom.development.js:15290
./src/index.js @ index.js:7
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:678
fn @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:88
0 @ registerServiceWorker.js:108
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:678
./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js.module.exports @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:724
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:724
index.js:2177 Warning: Invalid DOM property `class`. Did you mean `className`?
    in div (at App.js:13)
    in div (at App.js:11)
    in App (at index.js:7)
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ index.js:2177
printWarning @ warning.js:33
warning @ warning.js:57
validateProperty$1 @ react-dom.development.js:13539
warnUnknownProperties @ react-dom.development.js:13580
validateProperties$2 @ react-dom.development.js:13600
validatePropertiesInDevelopment @ react-dom.development.js:13639
setInitialProperties$1 @ react-dom.development.js:13906
finalizeInitialChildren @ react-dom.development.js:14989
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:8648
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:10132
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:10234
workLoop @ react-dom.development.js:10288
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:542
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:581
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:438
renderRoot @ react-dom.development.js:10366
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:11014
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:10967
requestWork @ react-dom.development.js:10878
scheduleWorkImpl @ react-dom.development.js:10732
scheduleWork @ react-dom.development.js:10689
scheduleTopLevelUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:11193
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:11231
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:15226
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:11102
renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:15225
render @ react-dom.development.js:15290
./src/index.js @ index.js:7
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:678
fn @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:88
0 @ registerServiceWorker.js:108
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:678
./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js.module.exports @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:724
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 93160685b6ed6746a2f2:724
StoreContainer.js:16 {data: Array(3), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
webpackHotDevClient.js:136 ./src/components/NavBarHeader.js
  Line 10:  Links must not point to "#". Use a more descriptive href or use a button instead  jsx-a11y/href-no-hash
printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:136
handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:153
./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:206
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/eventtarget.js.EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:51
(anonymous) @ main.js:274
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/main.js.SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js:272
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js.EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:50
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js:35
webpackHotDevClient.js:136 ./src/components/GoogleMap.js
  Line 28:  'marker' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<Modal>` instead of `<Modal.Dialog>`

Take a look at the [example of a basic modal from react-bootstraps component page](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/).

Comment: AAA!!!! I spent 2 days to find the solution. Thank you! I used static Modal example from the same page and added elements from the example below.